# convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm dx}{x\ln(1/x)}$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I need help checking if the integral:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm dx}{x\ln(1/x)}$$

converge.

here is what I did:

I looked at a smaller integral:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm dx}{\ln(1/x)}\lt \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm dx}{x\ln(1/x)}$$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm dx}{\ln(1/x)}=\int_0^1 -\frac{\mathrm dx}{\ln x}=\left[-\ln\big|\ln|x|\big|\right]_0^1$$

I got stuck here, although my intuition says it diverge.

How should I solve this?

edit: maybe I can use Abel\Dirichlet theorem?

Comment: Its almost easier to just solve the integral.  Note that $\ln\frac1x=-\ln x$ and by setting $u=\ln x$, you should end up with $$I=-\int_{-\infty}^0\frac1u~\mathrm du$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I didn't think about that :) is it possible to solve using Abel\Dirichlet theorem also?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. Sorry, I missed your invitation to join you in the chat room.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You can just check my profile page.

Comment: @segevp I don't see how those theorems apply here.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt thank you, have fun chatting ;)

Answer (score 1):

$$-\int_X^\frac 12\frac {dx}{x\ln (x)}= $$

$$-\Bigl [\ln (|\ln (x)|)\Bigr]_X^\frac 12=$$
$$\ln(|\ln (X)|)-\ln (\ln (2)) $$

which goes to $+\infty $ when $X\to 0^+$.

hence it diverges.

Comment: why did you change the integral upper limit to $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @segevp if it diverges, we do not need to study it near 1.

Comment: so if part of the integral diverge necessarily the whole integral diverge?

Comment: @segevp Yes of course.

Answer (score 1):

I substituted $x=1/z$ whence $dx = -\dfrac{dz}{z^2}$

Integration limits become at $x=1\to z=1$ at $x=0\to z\to +\infty$

So we have
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm dx}{x\ln(1/x)}=\int_{+\infty}^1\left( -\frac{z\mathrm dz}{z^2\ln(z)}\right)=\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm dz}{z\ln(z)}=\left.\ln\ln(z)\right|_1^{+\infty}$$
which diverges.

Hope this helps